# java - copying array list

Tags: java, arraylist, deep-copy

So the below method I'm aware causes both variables to point to the same object, but if I did want to find the simplest method to has ArrayList s2 exactly the same as s1, how would I do this?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<String> s1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
            s1.add(""+i);
        }
        ArrayList<String> s2 = s1;

    }
```

Comment: Note that you're doing an unnecessary String concatenation on the line in your `for` loop. Maybe the JVM will optimize that out, but I'd use `Integer.toString(i)` instead of `""+i` to get the String representation of an int.

Answer (score 5):

You should create s2 with s1 as parameter.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<String> s1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        s1.add(""+i);
    }
    ArrayList<String> s2 = new ArrayList<String>(s1);

}
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that while you now have two references to **different** lists, the references inside those lists are **the same**, so changes to objects stored in one will affect the other. Not an issue when working with Strings (as they're immutable), but a general point to bear in mind when working with lists of other types of object.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza's solution is also how I would do it, but you could also use `s2.addAll(s1)` or `Collections.copy(s1, s2)` after creating a new empty `ArrayList<String>`. The `Collections` and `Arrays` classes have a lot of other utility methods that you might want to review, because they'll come in handy at some point.

Comment: @rob I wasn't improving his code, just showing the easiest way to get a new `ArrayList<String>` that contains the same data that the `s1` ArrayList. Yes, I agree that there are other ways to do the task in hand, just showing one of the many ways :)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Yes, I understood that. :) I wanted to mention the other alternatives but didn't think it warranted a separate answer since yours was good. I also wanted to introduce Tim to the Collections and Arrays classes, because every Java programmer should know about those.