# Using Button To copy 1 list element into another list, but keep the second list contents

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I am using this event to copy the selected element of the list into another list that also has information in it. I am able to copy the element, but it is deleting the elements in list2 when I do. I am trying to copy and remove from one list to another and vice versa.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)  { 
    List<String> selectedValuesList = jList1.getSelectedValuesList();
    jList2.setListData(selectedValuesList.toArray(new String[selectedValuesList.size()]));    
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [java - copying array list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10457302/java-copying-array-list)

Comment: @Mathemats Wrong type of list ... `javax.swing.JList != java.util.List` ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer True, although he has a problem with the logic (I see no loops for example).

Comment: @Mathemats Yep, the OP is just plastering the new content over the old :P

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `setListData`, this is overwriting the contents.

Start by setting the `ListModel` for `jList2` to a `DefaultListModel`

```
jList2.setModel(new DefaultListModel());
```

Then use `addElement` instead

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
{ 
    List selectedValuesList = jList1.getSelectedValuesList();
    DefaultListModel model = (DefaultListModel)jList2.getModel();
    for (Object value : selectedValuesList) {
        model.addElement(value);
    }
}
```

See [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for more details